# Specify log settings for axis 1.4

Tags: java, log4j, axis, apache-commons-logging

I have a java app and I'm using axis to make soap calls.  Does anybody know how I can tell Axis to use my log4j.xml file located in my projects base directory instead of its internal properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make log4j.xml available in your classpath and log4j will pick it up. I know the name it looks for is [log4j.properties](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html) if you are using properties file but not sure what is the standard name it looks for when you are using xml based configuration.

Comment: I'm relatively new to java so can you be more specific with how to make my log4j.xml available in my classpath.  Thankyou

Comment: I figured it out.  I added DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml"); to my main method and it works.  Thanks